# Is there any ways to prevent user from modifying cookie via document.cookie in browser?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, setcookie

I'm developing an ReactJS app calling api from my server. After logging in, server returns an authentic-token and I need to store it in cookies (the key is `token` and value is the authentic-token from server. Now I'm using [universal-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie)). But when I assign `document.cookie` to another value like `token=xxx` in browser's console, the `token` in cookies will be modified. Is there any ways to prevent user from modifying the cookie via `document.cookie` ?
Thank you !

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you think it solves?

Comment: I just want to know if there is any way or not. Actually it doesn't matter. Thank you again :D

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the answer is **No**. You should never have to trust data from the browser as there are a myriad ways of manipulating it.

Instead you should make sure your backend server validates the cookie.

Comment: Thank you :D And certainly my backend server always validates the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent a user from modifying the token in the cookies. `universal-cookie` stores data in a particular way and it shouldn't be altered using `document.cookie`. Also, you should always validate the data in the cookie with the data in your backend as the user can manipulate the data in any way.

It would be better to use `universal-cookie` itself to do all the tasks related to cookies you want to do, as you can do almost everything with it. And you can also try out some other packages such as [react-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookies)

Comment: Yeah, my backend server always validates the data from client. Thank you for your question :D